# If pyparsing is not thread safe，why use RLock in _parseCache?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pyparsing

I found in core.py _parseCache function, it seems that a lock is used to make cache read/write mutual exclusion(I am noob in concurrency development). But pyparsing is not thread safe, when use multple threads to packrat parsing multiple string, corruption happens. So why use RLock?